# Как найти в строке файл и удалить его из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
2018/05/IMG_5116-150x150.jpg
2018/05/IMG_5075-150x150.jpg
2018/05/IMG_5040-150x150.jpg
```

все строки содержат название файла после поиска и замены мне нужно чтобы в них остались только даты

```
2018/05
2018/05
2018/05
2018/05
```

вообще изначально строки выгялдят так:

```
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5116-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5075-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5040-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5024-150x150.jpg
```

первую часть я очистил с помощью

```
$str = str_replace('http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/', '', $str);
```

но если есть способ с помощью одной функции вытащить из строки пару (2018/05),будет идеально

пока в голове есть только решение сделать из строки массив и достать из него нужные элементы, но это мне кажется будет большей нагрузкой, если вдруг есть альтернативный способ сделать то что мне надо за раз

Comment: `preg_replace('~/[^/]*$~', '', $s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать шаблон с поиском четырёх идущих подряд цифр `\d{4}`, разделённых слешем `/`, после которого следуют ещё две цифры `\d{2}`

```
$str = 'http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5116-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5075-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5040-150x150.jpg
http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5024-150x150.jpg';

preg_match_all('~\d{4}/\d{2}~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат - массив дат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '2018/05' (length=7)
      1 => string '2018/05' (length=7)
      2 => string '2018/05' (length=7)
      3 => string '2018/05' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку искомая подстрока у вас имеет постоянную длину, а префикс адреса всегда также постоянен, то в качестве альтернативы регуляркам предложу такой вариант:

```
$data = [
    "http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5116-150x150.jpg",
    "http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5075-150x150.jpg",
    "http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5040-150x150.jpg",
    "http://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_5024-150x150.jpg",
 ];


$result = array_map(function($v){
                  return substr($v, 35,7);
              }, $data);

print_r($result);
```